# How to make ip commands persist

Tags: iproute

I have a script (bottom of question) which adds a dummy link, adds some addresses to that link, and adds some routes to that link.

**How can I make `ip link`, `ip addr`, and `ip route` commands persist?**

I'm using Debian stretch,  NetworkManager is installed.

### Thought 1:

If I put this file in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` it might be called when the machine boots.  `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown` seems to point to this directory.

> **Update:** I tried, it wasn't a good idea

### Thought 2:

I might need to translate this into a different configuration language and put it in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/`, but the examples I've seen so far for configuring this file assumes that devices exist.  I haven't found a configuration line which is equivalent to `ip link add mocknet type dummy`.

This file relies on the `auto` keyword at the start of lines to identify physical interfaces (`auto mocknet`), but `mocknet` doesn't exist yet.

### Working script

```
ip link add mocknet type dummy

ip addr add 10.10.1.1/24 dev mocknet
ip addr add 10.10.2.1/24 dev mocknet
ip addr add 10.10.3.1/24 dev mocknet
ip addr add 10.10.4.1/24 dev mocknet
ip addr add 10.10.5.1/24 dev mocknet
ip addr add 10.10.6.1/24 dev mocknet
ip addr add 10.10.7.1/24 dev mocknet
ip addr add 10.10.8.1/24 dev mocknet
ip addr add 10.10.9.1/24 dev mocknet

ip link set mocknet up

ip route del 10.10.1.0/24 
ip route del 10.10.2.0/24 
ip route del 10.10.3.0/24 
ip route del 10.10.4.0/24 
ip route del 10.10.5.0/24 
ip route del 10.10.6.0/24 
ip route del 10.10.7.0/24 
ip route del 10.10.8.0/24 
ip route del 10.10.9.0/24 

ip route add 10.10.1.0/24 dev mocknet proto kernel scope link src 10.10.1.1 metric 6000
ip route add 10.10.2.0/24 dev mocknet proto kernel scope link src 10.10.2.1 metric 6000
ip route add 10.10.3.0/24 dev mocknet proto kernel scope link src 10.10.3.1 metric 6000
ip route add 10.10.4.0/24 dev mocknet proto kernel scope link src 10.10.4.1 metric 6000
ip route add 10.10.5.0/24 dev mocknet proto kernel scope link src 10.10.5.1 metric 6000
ip route add 10.10.6.0/24 dev mocknet proto kernel scope link src 10.10.6.1 metric 6000
ip route add 10.10.7.0/24 dev mocknet proto kernel scope link src 10.10.7.1 metric 6000
ip route add 10.10.8.0/24 dev mocknet proto kernel scope link src 10.10.8.1 metric 6000
ip route add 10.10.9.0/24 dev mocknet proto kernel scope link src 10.10.9.1 metric 6000
```

Comment: Thought 3, if you have systemd running: Translate it into a different language, and use `/etc/systemd/network/` configuration files.

Comment: What would an equivalent configuration look like in `/etc/systemd/network`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Thought 2** is correct.  Also, it isn't that tough to translate from this simple script into a correct file.  A nice surprise here is that `ip link set mocknet up` is automatic.  `man interfaces` gives some good information.  Here's the working file:

`/etc/network/interfaces.d/mocknet`:

```
# Mocknet: 
#    A mock network meant to replace parts of the real one if they don't exist.
# 
# We are creating a network sink called mocknet. It's a dummy, so data sent to 
# this is ignored. This is useful for when we want to run the simulation without
# all other machines connected. If a machine doesn't exist, then this prevents 
# that packet from being sent to the default route and spamming the LAN.

auto mocknet
iface mocknet inet manual
#
#   This creates the dummy interface.  Dummy means that data sent here will be 
#   ignored.
    pre-up /bin/ip link add mocknet type dummy
#
#   Here we add all of the IP adresses that we might have as host on the FFS.  
#   This guarantees that we can bind to these addresses for Rx and helps us make 
#   a route for Tx
    up /bin/ip addr add 10.10.1.1/24 dev mocknet
    up /bin/ip addr add 10.10.2.1/24 dev mocknet
    up /bin/ip addr add 10.10.3.1/24 dev mocknet
    up /bin/ip addr add 10.10.4.1/24 dev mocknet
    up /bin/ip addr add 10.10.5.1/24 dev mocknet
    up /bin/ip addr add 10.10.6.1/24 dev mocknet
    up /bin/ip addr add 10.10.7.1/24 dev mocknet
    up /bin/ip addr add 10.10.8.1/24 dev mocknet
    up /bin/ip addr add 10.10.9.1/24 dev mocknet
#
#   The previous line created some default routes. Those routes are super high 
#   priority (metric=0) so they override real connections if they exist. We 
#   don't want that so here we need to delete the default routes and then add 
#   good versions. Now if a packet is sent to something in this ip range it goes 
#   to mocknet.  `metric 6000` sets the route priority super low (a bigger 
#   number is lower priority so if it conflicts with a real device, that real 
#   device will take priority and data will be sent and not ignored.
    post-up /bin/ip route del 10.10.1.0/24 && /bin/ip route add 10.10.1.0/24 dev mocknet proto kernel scope link src 10.10.1.1 metric 6000
    post-up /bin/ip route del 10.10.2.0/24 && /bin/ip route add 10.10.2.0/24 dev mocknet proto kernel scope link src 10.10.2.1 metric 6000
    post-up /bin/ip route del 10.10.3.0/24 && /bin/ip route add 10.10.3.0/24 dev mocknet proto kernel scope link src 10.10.3.1 metric 6000
    post-up /bin/ip route del 10.10.4.0/24 && /bin/ip route add 10.10.4.0/24 dev mocknet proto kernel scope link src 10.10.4.1 metric 6000
    post-up /bin/ip route del 10.10.5.0/24 && /bin/ip route add 10.10.5.0/24 dev mocknet proto kernel scope link src 10.10.5.1 metric 6000
    post-up /bin/ip route del 10.10.6.0/24 && /bin/ip route add 10.10.6.0/24 dev mocknet proto kernel scope link src 10.10.6.1 metric 6000
    post-up /bin/ip route del 10.10.7.0/24 && /bin/ip route add 10.10.7.0/24 dev mocknet proto kernel scope link src 10.10.7.1 metric 6000
    post-up /bin/ip route del 10.10.8.0/24 && /bin/ip route add 10.10.8.0/24 dev mocknet proto kernel scope link src 10.10.8.1 metric 6000
    post-up /bin/ip route del 10.10.9.0/24 && /bin/ip route add 10.10.9.0/24 dev mocknet proto kernel scope link src 10.10.9.1 metric 6000
#
#   This cleans up the interface so it doesn't fail if we try to 
#   systemctl restart networking.
    post-down /bin/ip link del mocknet
```

I'm not sure whether `/bin/ip` or `/sbin/ip` is the "right" way to do this, but everything seems to work.

Comment: From the looks of the documentation (try `man interfaces`, `man ip`), the configuration file format is not 1-to-1 with the `ip` command features. For example, on a Debian 10.9 system, it's not clear if the `ip` command's `type` setting matches any config file options. In other words, it looks like using the `ip` commands is the current "right" way.