# Secondary (Virtual) Interface on Same NIC with DHCP

Tags: debian, networking, ip, dhcp, interface

I'm currently working on Buster, but the more portable the solution, the better.

I have a system for which I would like to add a second IP address to the same adapter. The initial IP address is DHCP, and I want the secondary interface to get its address via DHCP as well.

I have done the typical LMGTFY approach. Most all of the solutions I find pre-date using IP, and all of them so far have used static IPs. Also, without fail, all have made me wish I had a monitor and KB connected to my headless system after I rebooted.

The end result will be a system that will have a different name that resolves to a different IP address.

Since someone has downvoted this in the time it took me to get another beer, here's what I have checked:

- [Set up two IPs (one using DHCP and other static) over the same Interface](https://serverfault.com/questions/891191/set-up-two-ips-one-using-dhcp-and-other-static-over-the-same-interface): Did not come up after reboot, example is not DHCP
- [Getting 2 IP addresses on one network card, using DHCP](https://serverfault.com/questions/891191/set-up-two-ips-one-using-dhcp-and-other-static-over-the-same-interface): Did not come up after reboot, example is not DHCP
- [How to Have Multiple IP addresses on One NIC in Linux](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/bind-ip-interface/): Different version of Linux, files do not (seem to) correlate to Debian

None of these resulted in me having a working system after I've attempted to apply and/or translate the configuration changes.

Comment: Use a macvlan to create the second interface. I recommend moving it into a network namespace, to avoid the headaches the two IPs on the same interface give you. Also note that the second IP addr by DHCP doesn't buy you anything unless you can somehow use both IPs differently, which again likely requires a network namespaces.

Comment: I will give that a look, thank you.  I'm not a network person - I thought a vlan would bring into play a separate network routing space?

Comment: I read about macvlan and I'm not sure that's what I need, however, ipvlan does look promising.  An hour in and I have not made it work yet, but surely there's a way.

Comment: While `ip` may be new it's really only used for non-persistent changes.  Setting an IP with `ip` will not persist when you reboot. The original `interfaces` is still the way to handle this if you aren't using `networkmanager`.  `man interfaces` gives good examples for how to edit `/etc/network/interfaces`.  You can even use `ip` commands in `interfaces`.  [Here's a problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476539/how-to-make-ip-commands-persist) I solved a couple years ago with this.

Comment: Solving with IP is interesting, thanks for sharing that - it goes in the toolbox.  However, it still doesn't solve my problem/need.  I am using wireless so ipvlan is the only solution that looks like it will allow a second IP (because the mac would be the same) and pull it from DCHP.  That said I still have not solved it.